# npm install local package creates symbolic links

Tags: node.js, npm

I created a custom node.js package locally and installed it with npm in another local project where I want to use it. Everything is working perfectly, but pushing it to a remote git repository/web server, the package is not found by my application. Also, the package folder is empty on the webserver, while every file is present in my local node_modules directory. The command I used locally is:

```
npm install /local-system/htdocs/my-custom-local-package
```

Apparently the above command creates a symbolic link to my package. Is this normal behaviour of npm? And if so, how to copy the package instead of creating a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the package with the `--install-links` flag as it says at the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#install-links):

> NOTE: If you want to install the content of a directory like a package from the registry instead of creating a link, you would need to use the --install-links option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use npm-copy after npm install. Do you check the npm documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There is great **yalc** that helps to manage local packages. It helped me with local lib that I later deploy. Just pack project with .yalc directory (with or without /node_modules).  So just do:

```
npm install -g yalc 

in directory lib/$ yalc publish
```

in project:

```
project/$ yalc add lib

project/$ npm install
```

that's it.

**When You want to update stuff:**

```
lib/$ yalc push 

project/$ npm install
```

**Pack and deploy with Docker**

```
tar -czvf app.tar build/ .yalc/ src/ package.json package-lock.json
```

inDocker:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.9

ADD app.tar /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "src/index.js" ]
```